# Is there *ANY* way to download FTP files with Windows Phone 7 & .Net 4?

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-7, ftp, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I implement support for ftp in WP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022669/how-do-i-implement-support-for-ftp-in-wp7)

Hi all,

I'm trying to write a WP7 app to display Australian weather and to do this I need to directly download and process files on an FTP server containing all the data.

I was very surprised to see WP7 does not support FTP via the Framework so does anyone know any way around this?  I tried this code using WebClient but of course I get a NotSupportedException :-(

```
 Uri BOMUri = new Uri("ftp://ftp2.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDN10064.xml");
 client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "janeDoe@contoso.com");
 client.DownloadStringAsync(BOMUri, "100064_summary");
```

I thought maybe it might be possible to download an FTP file using HTTP but I'm not sure - anyone have any ideas how I might get around this (short of having to download all the files to an HTTP server via a normal WinForms or service)?

I *really* need to find an answer for this so any help would be really appreciated.

Mike